# How to kill the thread when the new activity is started and how to override the previous thread

Tags: android, android-intent

i have some 10 activities when the present activity is idle for 10 sec then it should go back to the main page

the code i used in each activity is

```
final Handler handler=new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
                public void run()
                {

                    handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Business_Personal.this,PrintoActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Thread.interrupted();
                }
            };

            handler.postDelayed(r, 10000);
            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while(true)
                        {
                            sleep(1000);
                            handler.post(r);

                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
```

if i use this above code then till 3rd activity its working fine but in 3rd activity time is out and it's coming back to the main page

i need the code when i enter into next activity it should kill the previous thread and create a new thread

or else

override that previous thread

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the thread by using some boolean value which you set to false on the Activity's onDestroy or onPause.

```
while(threadNeeded){
}

public onDestroy(){
  threadNeeded = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but the thread is running foreground instad of background the screen is blank